# Transform FAB to modal bottom sheet (or similar)

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I'm trying to make a FAB expand to become the bottom sheet similar to the "Within screen" example in [material.io](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button#types-of-transitions)

So that when I tap on
[this FAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDoqG.png)
animates to become
[this modal bottom sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yAaw.png)

Here is the code for this example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('Hello, World!')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
            builder: (context) {
              return AddEntryBottomSheet();
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddEntryBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Text('Hello, world!'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
            child: Text('More content'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You getting any error? And what you are able to achieve ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, but with this setup I'm only getting a normal modal bottom sheet that slides up from the bottom. What I want to achieve is to make the FAB expand to become the modal bottom sheet instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the result I wanted with the example below. Just use ExpandingFab as a FAB in a Scaffold

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandingFab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpandingFabState createState() => _ExpandingFabState();
}

class _ExpandingFabState extends State<ExpandingFab> {
  bool _cardIsOpen = false;
  double get cardWidth => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 32;
  double cardHeight = 200;

  Widget _renderFab() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _cardIsOpen = true;
        });
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
    );
  }

  Widget _renderUpsertEntryCard() {
    return Container(
      width: cardWidth,
      height: cardHeight,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Text('Hello, World!'),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _cardIsOpen = false;
              });   
            }, 
            child: Text('Close'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double w = _cardIsOpen ? cardWidth  : 56;
    double h = _cardIsOpen ? cardHeight : 56;

    return AnimatedContainer(
      curve: Curves.ease,
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: w,   maxWidth: w,
        minHeight: h,  maxHeight: h,
      ),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: _cardIsOpen ? Colors.blueGrey[100] : Colors.blue,
        boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[1],
        borderRadius: _cardIsOpen
            ? BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0.0))
            : BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
      ),
      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        transitionBuilder: (child, animation) => ScaleTransition(
          scale: animation,
          child: child,
        ),
        child: !_cardIsOpen ? _renderFab() : _renderUpsertEntryCard(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```